# How to configure PHP basedir for Joomla running on IIS shared hosting

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, iis

I have the following setup:

- IIS 10 with Plesk Onyx 17.8.11.
- Joomla 3.8.13/PHP 7.2.10. The website is hosted in shared hosting provider.

After installing [Gantry 5](http://gantry.org/downloads) I get the following warning on the Joomla *Control Panel* page:

> SplFileInfo::isFile(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(gantry-themes:/\beez3) is not within the allowed path(s): (D:/Inetpub/vhosts/xxx\;C:\Windows\Temp)

Looking at the *PHP Settings* tab of the Joomla *System Information* page I see the following setting:

> Open basedir  D:/Inetpub/vhosts/xxx\;C:\Windows\Temp\

As far as I can tell, the `D:/Inetpub/vhosts/xxx\` is incorrect since the root folder of the website is:

`D:/Inetpub/vhosts/xxx/yyy`

In fact, I had to set the *Path to Temp Folder* to `D:/Inetpub/vhosts/xxx/yyy/tmp` in the Joomla *Global Configuration Server Settings* in order to install [Gantry](http://gantry.org/downloads) using the Joomla *Install From Folder* method.

On the other hand, I cannot find a way to modify the value of `Open basedir` setting either from Plesk or otherwise. As a result, the Gantry component page reports the same error:

> Twig_Error_Runtime
>   An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("SplFileInfo::isFile(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(gantry-themes:/\beez3) is not within the allowed path(s): (D:/Inetpub/vhosts/xxx\;C:\Windows\Temp)").

Please note, that I refer to Gantry as an example; The same problem occurs for every other Joomla extension I tried to install.

Is there a way to properly configure Joomla/PHP on my setup?